# windows10を使用中に、外付けUSBHDDのubuntu22.04を実行する方法はあるか？

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

windows10でブラウザでubuntuの環境設定の方法を見つつ、同じマシンにUSBで外付けしたHDDのubuntu22.04を実行して環境設定をする方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 目的や状況は違うでしょうが、こんな記事が何かの参考になるかも？ [Windows環境(WSL2)で外付けSSD上にDocker環境を構築する手順](https://qiita.com/akatuki50/items/9c9e80c4744d1723f945), [Hyper-VにUbuntu 21.04を構築する](https://mebee.info/2021/04/27/post-33353/), [Windows10のHyper-V上でUbuntuを動かす](https://blackbird-blog.com/hyper-v-ubuntu-setup)

Answer (score 0):

Pro,Enterprise,Educationの場合のみになりますが、Hyper-Vであれば、パススルーでUSB-HDDを直接マウントできるようです。

1. USB-HDDを繋ぎます。
2. キーボード Win + X で表示されるメニューで「ディスクの管理」を選択します。
3. ディスクの管理で該当の **ディスク** を右クリックして「オフライン」にします。
4. 「Hyper-V マネージャー」を起動します。
5. 仮想マシンを「新規」で作成します。作成時に「仮想ハード ディスクの接続」で「後で仮想ハード ディスクを接続する」を選択します。(手元の検証では第2世代で行いましたが、第1世代でも可能かと思われます)
6. 仮想マシンの「設定」を開きます。

   1. (第2世代のみ)「ハードウェア」 > 「セキュリティ」で「テンプレート」を「Microsoft UEFI 認証機関」にします。(Ubuntu等はセキャアブート対応ですが、そうではないLinuxディストリビューションの場合はセキュアブートそのものを無効にする必要があります)
   2. 「ハードウェア」 > 「SCSI コントローラー」(第1世代の場合は「IDE コントローラー 0」)で「ハード ドライブ」を追加します。このとき、メディアのところで「物理ハードディスク」を選び、先程オフラインにしたディスクを選択します。
   3. 「管理」 > 「チェックポイント」で「チェックポイントを有効にする」のチェックを外して、チェックポイントを無効にします。
7. 設定を保存後、仮想マシンを起動します。

一応、上の方法でインストールするところまでは試しています。仮想と物理の違いで細かいところがうまくいかない可能性もありますので、後は試行錯誤してみて下さい。

参考記事: [Hyper-V 仮想マシンにパススルーディスク(Pass-through Disk)を使って外付けHDDディスクを接続する - Windows10](https://www.billionwallet.com/windows10/hyper-v-pass-through-disk.html)